# css keyframe transition best way to do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I am using Rico St.Cruz brillant working query.transit library but now I have to change some things to do with classes instead though not being this firm in CSS transitions. I tried to

**replace:**

JS:

```
$("#target_element").mouseenter( function() {

  $("#arr_left")
    .transition( { x: 3 }, 300,  'easeOutSine' )
    .transition( { x: 0 }, 300,  'easeInSine' ); 
  };

}
```

**with:**

JS:

```
$("#target_element").mouseenter( function() {

  $("#arr_left").addClass('hint');

}
```

CSS:

```
#arr_left.hint {
  -webkit-animation: hint_left 600ms;
  -moz-animation:    hint_left 600ms;
  -o-animation:      hint_left 600ms;
  animation:         hint_left 600ms;
}

@keyframes hint_left {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0);
    -o-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1); /* easeOutSine */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px);
    -moz-transform: translate(3px);
    -o-transform: translate(3px);
    transform: translate(3px);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715); /* easeInSine */
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715) ;
  }
}
```

but this new code does not work.

1) What I am doing wrong here?

2) What is the shortest code (browser compatible) to reach this?

Addition: I’d like to keep the "hint" class generic to address via JS with each arrow has a specific own translation property. Thanks so much in advance!

**EDIT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bg7w6jmh/61/

I added a fiddle. Note: I need the extra container for the arrow because it’s animated (rotated) in other places.
The aim is to make the little arrow smoothly move to the left 3px and back in to indicate the target_element being animated on click or swipe. For the values and easing see the keyframes. Thanks for help!

Comment: See my edit if you want. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to update my fiddle but it does not work at all. Seems that I lack some basic understanding of how to add keyframe transitions. :-( Somebody please give me a hint on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens to be ok now. While I was working endlessly on my fiddle I recognized that I missed a round bracket at the end of my event declaration…